# Angular js - On scroll up load more data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, infinite-scroll

I have developed a chatting system like Facebook. Now I want to do load earlier messages. Can anyone help me to do the functionality like when I scroll up it should load earlier messages same like Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [ngInfiniteScroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll). With this module, it is very easy to implement what you want. Here is an example:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
    <img ng-repeat='image in images' ng-src='http://placehold.it/225x250&text={{image}}'>
  </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      $scope.images.push(last + i);
    }
  };
});
```

If you are using [Bower](http://bower.io/), you can install if with `bower install ngInfiniteScroll.`

Comment: yes, you are right but i want to add data on scroll up.Is it possible with ngInfiniteScroll?

Comment: no this isn't possible unfortunatley :( i have found https://github.com/LightZam/zInfiniteScroll works but i am having issues getting the scroll to stay where it is when it loads more

Comment: @Horse can you create issue for me to describe your problem?

Comment: guys, is there a way to transform element with ngInfiniteScroll in 180 degree? so it will be useful for scroll up. Do you think it's possible?